# HDTV as wireless monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdtv, ps3

I vaguely remember hearing of some solution that would allow you to use an HDTV as an additional wireless monitor for your computer. It would work exactly like an extra monitor connected to the computer (dual monitor setup).

I have a PS3, but I don't remember if the solution required one.

Has anybody heard of this?  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Both [Intel and Netgear](http://www.intel.com/consumer/products/technology/wirelessdisplay.htm) have teamed up to produce a device called Push2TV. As far as I know it only works with the i3, i5, and i7 Core Intel chipsets.

The technology is known as WiDi

[image]